# website gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, apache, wamp

My site is pcc.edu.ph domain name is hosted in zoneedit.com, and I am trying to launch my website and make it live on the internet, oh and one more thing I am also using wamp 2.5 as server, and I'm using my computer as a webserver. I have followed the tutorials that was posted over the internet but nothing worked, I think there is something wrong with the apache setup, any suggestions?

here is what my apache httpd.conf
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nig7aro3mfg7cv2/httpd.conf?dl=0

any more suggestions?

Comment: I'm getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, most likely due to a misconfigured DNS setup, or your LAN firewall.

Comment: my name servers are going to ns14.zoneedit.com
ns6.zoneedit.co.uk , my firewall allows the port, actually i tried to theck through the internet if port 80 via my external IP is open, and it says its open

Comment: here is a snapshot of my settings https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuox7r5yyjnupia/xd.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You might consider posting this to serverfault.com as well.

Comment: thanks, i will do that too

Comment: Is your site accessible via a browser locally?