# href php code shows image on my pc but not on others pcs

Tags: php, xampp

I am using xampp and have the image on  htdocs directory, its shows the image on my pc where xampp is installed but when accessing the pc from other 
pcs the image not shows .what shows is simply a very small cube similar to empty image in the upper side of the screen.

I have the photo in htdocs folder.
And i have the site with its directories in 
/xampp/htdocs/products1,2,3...and so on.

I tried playing with the settings of virtual server but to no available.

Here is the source code Pain67:     `<?php echo '<a href="kqzyfj.com/… src="localhost/image.jpg"; /></a>'; exit; ?>`'; exit; ?>

And Barak how can i check in the image source please? did u mean the source code of the image?

Comment: check the image src

Comment: Posting a source code would be helpful

Comment: Here is the source code Pain67:
<?php
echo '<a href="http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-8343045-12808288?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gearbest.com%2Fchargers-cables%2Fpp_650741.html%3Fwid%3D21"><img src="http://localhost/image.jpg" /></a>';
 exit;
 ?>

And Barak what can i check in the image source please? did u mean the source code of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Some points to troubleshoot it yourself,

1. Navigate the page (which does not show the image) in a browser like firefix/chrome.
2. Press F12 function key to open the developer console.
3. Go to the "network" tab in the dev console.
4. Check the image request's full url.  And ensure
   the below.

   - The url path is available in the server. You can copy the full url navigate it in a new tab of the browser.
   - What is the response code for the image request. If it is not 200 then check the reason for your specific http response
     code.
   - Example    404 - indicates the image is not found in the server.
   - Take action to    resolve the specific response code. Say if it is
                404 then the url    (relative path) in the image tag in your page should be corrected to    exactly point to the right
     path.
   - Finally if possible share the status code in this question, lets find out the solutions for that.. :)

Comment: I troubleshooted as u said Satheesh K and i get ERR_connection_refused

Comment: Some of the below could help you to resolve this.. Please have a try..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30448399/php-server-err-connection-refused

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762616/website-gives-err-connection-refused

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762616/website-gives-err-connection-refused

This type error may happen due to various reasons.. the server is not configured to allow the request (image) resource..

Comment: After seeing your source code, my observation is.. why we need to give the "localhost" in the src attribute? Give the relative path iof the image  instead..